# How to remove a class with specific name from HTMLElement in webbrowser control C#?

Tags: c#, controls

I'm adding a class to HTMLElement like this :

```
HtmlElement curElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
curElement.SetAttribute("className", "MyClass");
```

How can I remove a class from HTMLElement inside webbrowser control?